# A fix/workaround for unsupported Safari Extensions in Safari 12?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

The latest Safari update (12.0, Sept 17, 2018) turns off some and and stops supporting other extensions.

[image]

E.g., many people use Pocket's Safari Extension to save items to a OS-independent list. But I don't see Pocket on Apple's new list of supported Safari Extensions (https://itunes.apple.com/us/story/id1377753262). That might be why Pocket now recommends that Mac users just use their Mac app: https://help.getpocket.com/article/1042-using-pocket-for-safari

Pocket may update their extension such that Apple starts supporting it again. Until then, there might be a javascript bookmark(let) for saving items to Pocket (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4550) or a Pocket email address to which you can send items to your account (https://getpocket.com/add/).

But are there fixes/workarounds that would allow no-longer-supported Safari Extensions to work in Safari 12?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually install extensions through the developer menu. Enable Developer option in Safari (in preferences). Under the Developer menu, choose 'allow unsigned extensions'. Once that's checked off, under the developer menu again open Extension Builder and choose the option to add extension. This will allow you to add new extensions. The one caveat is you have to reload it when you reboot.
You can find a step by step here https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/install-any-safari-extension-macos-mojave/

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but this might still help someone (I landed here looking for the "official" ways to deal with this situation).

Here are the two available options:

- Install the app from the App Store, click on the Share button in the Toolbar, if Pocket is not there, click "More…" (last option) and check Pocket: the drawback is that you won't be able to add tags from there (you must do it from the app)
- Install the bookmarklet as one of the first 9 items, you will be able to trigger it with a keyboard shortcut (alt+cmd+1…9). This option lets you add tags.

To install the bookmarklet:

- visit https://getpocket.com/add?sb=1
- open the Bookmarks (click on the "Show sidebar" icon in Safari Toolbar)
- drag the button to the Bookmark list (in a top position - 1 to 9)

I did both, but I feel like I'll mostly add items using the bookmarklet.